# How to manually add a column referencing a model in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the current modeling:

```
A House belongs_to User
A User has_one House
```

Which means that the `House` model has a reference to `User`. My Factory for User, looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    house
  end
end
```

What this does is basically creating a User and a House that references that User.

Now, I have introduced a `column` in `User` called `house_id` and I want to be able to allow the Factory to work as it is, but also, fill the `house_id` with the House that was created.  The reason why I am doing this is because I want to change the reference direction incrementally.

I have done it like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    house
    house_id { House.find_by(user_id: id).id }
  end
end
```

But I suspect there might be a better way to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you use FactoryGirl in RSpec? If so, you can specify house_id when building or creating in spec file outside of factory file, I think.

Comment: But I want to have it as part of the factory to avoid being explicit every time I create the instance

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have the wrong idea of how `has_one` and `belongs_to` relations work.

`belongs_to` sets up a 1-1 or 1-to-many relationship and places the foreign key column on *this* models table. In the case its `houses.user_id` which references `users.id`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :house 
end

class House  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Secondly specs should not hinge on records being created sequentially. It will create brittle specs and ordering issues. Instead let factory girl do its job in creating objects for you.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    house
  end
end 

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :house do
    user
  end
end
```

And don't assume that records have a given id:

```
# bad
get :show, id: 1

# good
get :show, id: user.to_param
```

If you need to setup a record which is explicitly associated somewhere you can just pass a user or house option:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:house) { create(:house, user: user) }

it 'should be associated with the correct user' do
  expect(house.user).to eq user
end
```